# Selecting COUNT of a table along with selecting itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have an INT variable `@length` set to number of rows in my result table in procedure.
How can I set this without selecting my data twice?
What I do currently is this:

```
SELECT [data] FROM [mytable]
SET @length = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [mytable] WHERE [Condition])
```

However since my conditions are complicated and number of data is fairly a lot I feel like this is not optimal.

I could create a temp table and select my data into it and count length of it which seems to be a better approach but I wanted to know if there are any better solutions. thanks for the answers

Comment: You can use [@@rowcount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: this works fine but creates another problem. I need to Select the @@ROWCOUT before the select result itself. the order matters. @Stu

Comment: Perhaps a window function `COUNT(*) OVER ()`. It's unclear what you want to *do* with this number

Comment: Aside: Values of `output` parameters might not be populated until after the client retrieves the recordset, e.g. [Closing the DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader?redirectedfrom=MSDN#closing-the-datareader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use @@rowcount immediately after you `select` to return last operation rowcount:

```
select [data] from [mytable]
set @length=@@rowcount
```

Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).